# Node.js and the Filesystem: is this a race condition?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I have the following code inside a class.  (It's coffeescript-- and it's for a couchdb utility!-- but this is really a node.js question).  I'm attempting to do things The Node Way, using Node 0.49, and that means using asynchronous calls for filesystem operations.  At first, I was pulling my hair out because `this.sentinel` went to zero several times during the course of processing, so I know I'm doing something wrong there.  But then I hit an even weirder issue: down in load_directory, see those `console.log()` calls?  Watch when happens when I run this.

```
check_sentinel: ->
    @sentinel--
    if @sentinel == 0
        @emit('designDirLoaded', @object)

load_file: (rootdir, filename, object) ->
    @sentinel++
    fname = path.join(rootdir, filename)
    @manifest.push(fname)
    fs.readFile fname, (err, data) =>
        object[filename] = data
        @check_sentinel()

load_directory: (dirpath, object) ->
    @sentinel++
    fs.readdir dirpath, (err, files) =>
        for fname in files
            console.log("X1: ", fname)
            fs.stat path.join(dirpath, fname), (err, stats) =>
                console.log("X2: ", fname)
                if stats.isFile()
                    @load_file(dirpath, fname, object)
                if stats.isDirectory()
                    object[fname] = {}
                    @load_directory(path.join(dirpath, fname), object[fname])
        @check_sentinel()
```

Here's what I get:

```
X1:  memberByName.js
X1:  memberByClub.js
X2:  memberByClub.js
X2:  memberByClub.js
```

This is surreal, and it *looks* a lot like a race condition.  "memberByName" gets passed to `fs.stat()`, which in turn passes "memberByClub" to `load_file()`, implying... what?  That because `load_file()` returned immediately, it raced around and presented the next file name in the array to the function call?  Or do I have some misunderstanding about the persistence of values in a given scope?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, what you see is expected. One thing you have to remember is that `fs.stat` is asynchronous. So, the outer loop (`for fname in files`) will finish looping before any of the callbacks to `fs.stat` is called.

The reason why you see `memberByClub.js` twice is that you are using `fname` in the logging statement, but that variable is from the closure, which has changed by the time your callback to `fs.stat` is called.

You can wrap the inner loop with `do (fname) =>` to get the correct logging statements, but I think you need to restructure your code to achieve what you are trying to do with the whole class.

```
load_directory: (dirpath, object) ->
    @sentinel++
    fs.readdir dirpath, (err, files) =>
        for fname in files
            do (fname) =>
                console.log("X1: ", fname)
                fs.stat path.join(dirpath, fname), (err, stats) =>
                    console.log("X2: ", fname)
                    if stats.isFile()
                         @load_file(dirpath, fname, object)
                    if stats.isDirectory()
                        object[fname] = {}
                        @load_directory(path.join(dirpath, fname), object[fname])
        @check_sentinel()
```

Comment: Thank you.  It *was* my misunderstanding the interaction of the scope and asynchrony.  Funny how I've never hit anything like that in years of client-side programming.  And I get to add the `do` operator to my coffeescript arsenal.